# Elementary operations on schemes

Tags: algebraic-topology

In Munkres topology section 76, the "cancel" operation is introduced: one can replace the scheme $w_i=y_0aa^{-1}y_1$ by the scheme $y_0y_1$.

Munkres explains this in Figure 76.3. I can not understand this doesn't affecting the resulting quotient space?

Thanks!!!

Comment: And for those of us without a copy of Munkres's book at hand?

Comment: What's the context here? What you're calling a "scheme" is not the usual sense of the term.

Comment: Sorry, I can't upload the picture of the page in Munkres' Topology

Answer (score 0):

One possible explanation that I prefer:

Imagine the two adjacent edges that corresponds to $aa^{-1}$. Then the local picture near these edges would look like the circular sector in the following picture:

[image]

Then it is clear that increasing the angle of the circular sector is a homeomorphism. But increasing the angle to be $2\pi$ would make the circular sector look like $R^2$, and if you consider neighboring edges $y_0$ and $y_1$, then after this deformation the two edges $y_0$ and $y_1$ are now adjacent. So the resulting word for the scheme is $y_0y_1$.

Comment: I like your explanation, although it is not the explanation for the original proof in Munkres' book.

Comment: Actually it is. See that the angle between $a$ and $b$ increases to $\pi$ so that the word $aa^{-1}$ (or more precisely the word $cc^{-1}=(ab)(ab)^{-1}$) disappears into the interior. The same thing happens in my picture.

Comment: In fact, the only confusion in the original proof is why we can replace $ab$ by $c$?